# Error connecting to postgresql foreign server using SSL

Tags: postgresql, ssl, foreign-data-wrapper

I'm having trouble using SSL to connect to a foreign server using postgres_fdw. I had this working on a different server, but seemingly the same process is not working on my new machine.

I mostly follow the same steps as this [Percona blog](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/09/30/postgresql_fdw-authentication-changes-in-postgresql-13/) and create my server with the following command:

```
create
    server my_fdw
    foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw
    options (
        host 'localhost',
        port '5432',
        dbname 'my_foreign_db',
        use_remote_estimate 'on',
        sslrootcert '/home/myhome/.postgresql/root.crt',
        sslcert '/home/myhome/.postgresql/postgresql.crt',
        sslkey '/home/myhome/.postgresql/postgresql.key',
        sslmode 'verify-full'
    )
;

grant usage on foreign server my_fdw to myuser;

create user mapping
    for myuser
    server my_fdw
    options (password_required 'false')
;
```

I have no problem connecting to the primary database using SSL.
However, when I try to access the foreign server, e.g.:

```
import 
    foreign schema foreign_schema
    from server my_fdw
    into local_schema
;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not connect to server "my_fdw"
DETAIL:  connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: could not read root certificate file "/home/myhome/.postgresql/root.crt": Permission denied
```

The `root.crt` file is owned by the `myhome` user and permissions are set to 0600.
I can (temporarily) change the permissions of the `root.crt` file to be more permissive, which will bypass this specific error, but then I will get the same error for the other files. However, changing the permissions of these files will cause postgres to fail because they must be `0600` or lower.

It seems that postgres is trying to access the SSL files as a different OS user when executing a command related to the foreign server. Any ideas on what is going on or how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it is using a different user--the user who owns the database server processes.  This would usually be 'postgres'.  You might need to make a copy of those files, and do a `chown` on the copy.

Comment: I don't think that's the way it is supposed to work. As far as I understand it should be reading the key files as the user who is executing the client process (e.g., psql). There is nothing about separate copies of the key files in the Percona blog and I didn't have to make copies for the previous server I had working. Regardless, I copied the certificates to /tmp and change the owner to postgres and changed the create server code to look for them there. That gives a new error: **ERROR:  could not connect to server "worthy_fdw"** ...  **fe_sendauth: no password supplied.**

Comment: There is no code in libpq to proxy certs stored on the client through to the FDW.  Maybe in both the tutorial and your previous set up, the OS user running the client and OS user owning the server were the same.  Regarding you new error, when you updated the mapping, it looks like you left off the `password_required 'false'`

Comment: I didn't leave off the `password_required 'false'` options, but I think I had a problem with my `pg_hba.conf` file. I had an entry for `host` using scram-sha-256 and also for `hostssl` with cert clientcert and map. I think this was confusing the connection. Removing the `host` entry and keeping only the `hostssl` entry fixed the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah, right.  Leaving off `password_required 'false'` would have generated a different error message.  Glad you figured it out despite the red herring.